# Google Maps API with multiple markers / modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API JS v.3 that has several hundred markers. I want to open a modal with info specific to the marker they clicked on. I'm plan on using PHP and AJAX to get the modal data from the MySQL Database, but I'm not sure how to determine which marker the user clicked...

Any help is greatly appreciated

`

```
        var map;

        //icon variables
        /*
        var dem = 'path/to/blue/icon.png';
        var rep = 'path/to/red/icon.png';
        var oth = 'path/to/grey/icon.png';
        */
        var locations = [

            <?php
              $c = 0;
              $nr = mysqli_num_rows($gethouses);
              while($z = mysqli_fetch_array($gethouses)):
            ?>
            ['<?php echo $z['name_first'].' '.$z['name_last']; ?>', <?php echo $z['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $z['lng']; ?>, 4],
            <?php

              $c++;
              endwhile;
            ?>
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_world_map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.675, -119.98),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;
        var markers = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
            })(marker, i));
        }

        function AutoCenter() {
        // Create a new viewpoint bound
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // Go through each...
        $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
        });
        // Fit these bounds to the map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        AutoCenter();

        </script>`
```

Comment: What does your existing code look like?

Comment: I added it to the original question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom parameter in your `marker` object (which value ideally should be unique).

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        custom_param: some_unique_value
    });

    ....
}
```

Then on your marker `click` event you can identify which marker is clicked by getting the value in this case `marker.custom_param`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        // make use of `marker.custom_param`
        var myCustomParam = marker.custom_param;
    }
    })(marker, i));
}
```